# How do I configure portable parallel builds in CMake?

Tags: cmake, parallel-builds

Is it somehow possible to be able to have a parallel build no matter which build tool is used?

Under Unix we can add `make -jN` where N are the number of threads, and under Windows I added to the `CXX_FLAG "/MP"` which is then used in Visual Studio to parallel build...(?) How can I make my version such that `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` is not always extended when I run CMake?

What is a general solution?

I came up with this:

```
# Add some multithreaded build support
MARK_AS_ADVANCED(MULTITHREADED_BUILD)
set(MULTITHREADED_BUILD 12 CACHE STRING "How many threads are used to build the project")
if(MULTITHREADED_BUILD)
    if(${CMAKE_GENERATOR} MATCHES "Unix Makefiles")
            message(STATUS ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL})
            set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -j${MULTITHREADED_BUILD}")
            message(STATUS "Added arguments to CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL: ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}")
    elseif(MSVC)
      set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MP")
      message(STATUS "Added parallel build arguments to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
    endif()
endif()
```

Comment: Not sure it can be done, don't think its a good idea anyway. CMake describes how the project is build and how make does its thing is a different level from CMake.

Comment: Exetnding your approach just add `-DMULTITHREADED_BUILD=12` to the command line of cmake. and remove the `SET(MULTITHREADED_BUILD ...)`

Comment: In my case with Eclipse CDT results in error: "/usr/bin/make -j8" all 
Cannot run program "/usr/bin/make -j8": Unknown reason

Error: Program "/usr/bin/make -j8" not found in PATH

Comment: My CMake / Eclipse CDT error was due to CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM bug: http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15497

Comment: As this post is a little bit old, users of CMake >= 3.12.0 should consider the answer of @usr1234567

Answer (score 104, accepted):

With CMake 3.12 this is possible. From the [release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.12.html#command-line):

> The `cmake(1)` Build a Project (`cmake --build`) gained `--parallel [<jobs>]` and `-j [<jobs>]` options to specify a parallel build level. They map to corresponding options of the native build tool.

[As mentioned by dkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688549/how-do-i-configure-portable-parallel-builds-in-cmake#comment92443646_50883540), you can also set the environment variable `CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL`.

Links to CMake's documentation:

- *[Build a Project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode)*
- *[CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL.html)*

Comment: You can also set the env var `CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL`

Comment: What does "They map to corresponding options of the native build tool" exactly mean? For example it does not seem to automatically set the `/MP` flag for MSVC when using CMake 3.16.4 and Ninja 1.10.0. So it seems for a true/full parallel build there is still no cross-platform solution available.

Answer (score 26):

If you have CMake v2.8.8 or higher, you may use [**Ninja**](https://ninja-build.org/) as an alternative of [GNU **`make`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/):

```
mkdir build
cd    build
cmake -G Ninja ..
ninja              # Parallel build (no need -j12)
```

or

```
mkdir build
cd    build
cmake -G Ninja ..
cmake --build .    # Parallel build using Ninja
```

As you can see, no need to use `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`, the build is run in parallel by default, optimizing the number of jobs depending on available CPU cores.

Ninja is based on a low-level JSON configuration to speed up the startup phase. Therefore its JSON configuration is not easy to write by hand, and I always generate it using a high-level tool/IDE:

- [CMake v2.8.8](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-April/049955.html) (2012)
- [Qt Creator v2.6](https://www.slicer.org/wiki/Documentation/Labs/Ninja#Using_it) (2012)
- [KDevelop v4.6](https://www.kdevelop.org/46/kdevelop-460-final-released) (2013)
- [Meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson_(software)#Usage) on Linux (2013)
- ... see the generators of Ninja configuration at https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/wiki/List-of-generators-producing-ninja-build-files

As a C++ build often requires lots of memory, your computer must provide as much memory as the number of CPU cores.

As pointed out by [Ruslan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673852/ruslan), CMake [3.12](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/tag/v3.12.0) (2018) has a [new option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/release/3.12.html#command-line) `cmake --build -j <N>` to limit build to `<N>` cores (jobs) thus limiting the memory consumption (see also the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode)). If you use an older CMake version, you can still use `cmake --build -- -j <N>`. The option `--` tells to CMake to pass the rest directly to the underlying builder tool, here it is Ninja.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence: you can limit number of cores used with `-j N` option, thus the amount of memory used.

Comment: Thank you Ruslan  Three years after my answer, CMake has finally the option `-j N` I was waiting for. Have fun 

Comment: Before CMake 3.12 that you could just pass this option to Ninja — either running it directly as in your first snippet, or appending `-- -jN` after `cmake --build` (this `--` feature of `--build` exists even in CMake 2.8.0).

Comment: Thank you @Ruslan   . I was aware about the `--` option that I used with `make`. But I never used it with `ninja`.  Maybe in 2015, `ninja` had no option `-j <N>`... or I was not using it correctly...  I have updated the answer to fit your experience. Thanks 

Comment: using the new cmake -j <N> option if passing `-j 0` it will use all the cores automatically, like an autodetect the max cores availables and use them all?

Answer (score 16):

As already mention above one can use `--parallel [<jobs>]` (or `-j [<jobs>]`) option of CMake to build solution in parallel.

But I would like to note that in Windows a command

```
cmake.exe --build --parallel <jobs>
```

starts a root MSBuild process with the following arguments:

```
msbuild.exe /m:<jobs> /p:CL_MPCount=1 <another-useful-arguments...>
```

This means the root MSBuild process will start multiple child MSBuild processes due to `/m:<jobs>` (or `/maxcpucount:<jobs>`). But each of this child MSBuild runs at most one compiler process due to `/p:CL_MPCount=1` argument (for more details find [this link](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20564)). In other words each MSBuild can compile at most one source file at the same time.

To overcome this limitation one may call CMake in the following way:

```
cmake.exe --build --parallel <n_msbuild> -- /p:CL_MPcount=<n_cl>
```

This approach sets [`/MP` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/mp-build-with-multiple-processes?view=msvc-150) thereby allows multiple compiler processes under each MSBuild instance.

---

And for the record. To configure builds ran form Visual Studio GUI one need to go to *Settings*:

- Option *"Projects and Solutions → Build And Run → maximum number of parallel projects build"* affects on `maxcpucount`.
- Option *"Projects and Solutions → VC++ Project Settings → Build → Maximum Concurrent C++ Compilations"* represents the default boundary to `/MP`.

Answer (score 10):

Now it is very simple to parallel build with cmake. You can add "-j jobs_number" when using "cmake --build". For example:

```
cmake --build . -j 24
```

More details can be found in CMAKE manual: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode

> --parallel [], -j [] The maximum number of concurrent processes to use when building. If  is omitted the native build
> tool’s default number is used.
>
> The CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL environment variable, if set, specifies
> a default parallel level when this option is not given.
>
> Some native build tools always build in parallel. The use of 
> value of 1 can be used to limit to a single job.

Comment: When I try that I get `Unknown argument -j` . This is on ubuntu, cmake version 3.10.2

Comment: @pellucidcoder the reason might be that you need CMake 3.12 at least

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this cross-platform. The -jN option is a parameter to make, and not part of the generated Makefile. However, you could have CMake generate a Bash script that runs make for your project using -jN (where the script looks up the number of cores you have).

Comment: For Visual Studio: `msbuild your_project.sln /maxcpucount:N`

Comment: @JeanDavy: You can even pass this parameter using the CMake build tool by calling `cmake --build . -- /maxcpucount:8` as CMake passes all parameters following the "empty" `--` to the build tool.

Comment: @RolandSarrazin yep, my current script is `cmake --build .  --target install --config release -- /m` and it seems to be working on all cores. Thanks to [this discussion](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-November/047784.html). I also suggest to not specify exact number, in this case MSBuild will consider that build must be performed on all available cores, but not more than exist.

Comment: No longer true. Beginning with 3.12, CMake offers according flags. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have settled down to writing a `parallelmake.sh` script for `Unix Makefiles`-based generators. This is done here: https://github.com/gabyx/ApproxMVBB

And the relevant parts in the the CMake file:

https://github.com/gabyx/ApproxMVBB/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L89

```
# Add some multithreaded build support =====================================================================================================
MARK_AS_ADVANCED(MULTITHREADED_BUILD)
SET(MULTITHREADED_BUILD ON CACHE BOOL "Parallel build with as many threads as possible!")
if(MULTITHREADED_BUILD)
    if(${CMAKE_GENERATOR} MATCHES "Unix Makefiles")
            file(COPY ${ApproxMVBB_ROOT_DIR}/cmake/parallelmake.sh DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
                FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
                NO_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS
            )
            SET(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/parallelmake.sh")
            MESSAGE(STATUS "Set make program to ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/parallelmake.sh")
    elseif(MSVC)
      SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" "/MP")
      MESSAGE(STATUS "Added parallel build arguments to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
    endif()
endif()
# ========================================================================================================================================
```

Comment: With CMake 3.12, it's better to use the official way.