# How to build a CMake project in parallel on all available cores?

Tags: optimization, cmake, build, concurrency

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633074/set-the-number-of-threads-in-a-cmake-build/50883555) shows how to build a CMake project using a specified numbers of cores. For example if I wanted to use 10 cores, I could invoke CMake like this:

```
cmake --build . -j 10
```

My question is: how can I build using **all** my available cores. I effectively want CMake to autodetect my core count and use all of them.

Comment: You can use Ninja generator, it will utilize all your cores.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[As of CMake 3.22](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project), there is no standard way to do this. However, there are a few practical approaches.

1. If you use the `Ninja` or `Ninja Multi-Config` generators, on any platform, simply running the build with `cmake --build /path/to/build-dir` will use all cores.
2. If you are on a UNIX-like command line, you can run `cmake --build . -j $(nproc)`
3. If you are on Windows/cmd, you can run `cmake --build . -j %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%`

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t know that using the Ninja generator would automatically deal with this. I will just switch to using it as this seems to me to be the easiest, least error-prone and most future-proof solution out of the three.

Comment: It was really worth it. Now a full rebuild of my project project takes only a few seconds, rather than a few minutes. And linking is nearly instantaneous.

Comment: CMake Warning:
  Ignoring extra path from command line: