# From CMake setup 'make' to use '-j' option by default

Tags: cmake, parallel-builds

I want my CMake project to be built by `make -j N`, whenever I call `make` from the terminal. I don't want to set `-j` option manually every time.

For that, I set *CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM* variable to the specific command line. I use the `ProcessorCount()` function, which gives the number of procesors to perform build in parallel.

When I do `make`, I do not see any speed up. However if I do `make -j N`, then it is built definitely faster.

Would you please help me on this issue? (I am developing this on Linux.)

Here is the snippet of the code that I use in `CMakeList.txt`:

```
include(ProcessorCount)
ProcessorCount(N)
message("number of processors: "  ${N})
if(NOT N EQUAL 0)
  set(CTEST_BUILD_FLAGS -j${N})
  set(ctest_test_args ${ctest_test_args} PARALLEL_LEVEL ${N})
  set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -j ${N}")      
endif()
message("cmake make program" ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM})
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: None part of your code run anything. So, what do you want to speed up? Note, that **cmake phase cannot be parallelisized**: CMake scripts are processes sequentially, line by line, like in other scripting languages like python. As opposite, **build phase** may be parallelized and `make -j` does exactly this.

Comment: Some advice regarding CMake / build perfomance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37327526/2799037

Comment: I know it does not run, It is a segment of CMakeList.txt, I am simply trying to set the CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM and want to envoke "make -j N" each time that I call make from the terminal, instead of setting it explicitly in the terminal  each time ,

Comment: I would recommend to use [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/) as a replacement for `make`. It's faster and uses all available cores for compiling/linking by default.

Comment: @DrJ: I have added your comment into the question post, as it clarifies the problem a lot. In the future, tend to do that by your hands. On Stack Overflow all information which **describes the problem** should be **in the question post**. Comments are *temporary*.

Comment: Trying to do this is [not portable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688549/how-to-configure-portable-parallel-builds-in-cmake).

Comment: How to use N-1 cores ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via setting the [CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) variable you want to affect the build process. But:

1. This variable affects only the build via `cmake --build`, not on *native tool* (`make`) call:

   > The `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` variable is set for use by project code. The value is also used by the cmake(1) `--build` and ctest(1) `--build-and-test` tools to launch the native build process.
2. This variable should be a *CACHE*d one. It is used in such way by *make*-like generators:

   > These generators store CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM in the CMake cache so that it may be edited by the user.

   That is, you need to set this variable with

   ```
   set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM <program> CACHE PATH "Path to build tool" FORCE)
   ```
3. This variable should refer to the **executable** itself, not to a program with arguments:

   > The value may be the full path to an executable or just the tool name if it is expected to be in the PATH.

   That is, value "make -j 2" cannot be used for that variable (splitting arguments as list

   ```
   set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM make -j 2 CACHE PATH "Path to build tool" FORCE)
   ```

   wouldn't help either).

In summary, you may redefine the behavior of `cmake --build` calls with setting the *CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM* variable to the **script**, which calls `make` with parallel options. But you **may not affect the behavior of direct `make` calls**.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer

Comment: You may create an alias for "make -jN"

Answer (score 15):

In case you want to speed up the build you can run multiple make processes in parallel but not cmake.
To perform every build with predefined number of parallel processes you can define this in **MAKEFLAGS**.

Set MAKEFLAGS in your environment script, e.g. ~/.bashrc as you want:

```
export MAKEFLAGS=-j8
```

On Linux the following sets MAKEFLAGS to the number of CPUs - 1: (Keep one CPU free for other tasks while build) and is useful in environments with dynamic ressources, e.g. VMware:

```
export MAKEFLAGS=-j$(($(grep -c "^processor" /proc/cpuinfo) - 1))
```

New from cmake v3.12 on:

The command line has a new option `--parallel <JOBS>`.

Example:

```
cmake --build build_arm --parallel 4 --target all
```

Example with number of CPUs- 1 using nproc:

```
cmake --build build_arm --parallel $(($(nproc) - 1)) --target all
```

Comment: Be warned that some shells (zsh) in extended glob mode expand `^processor` as a glob pattern, make sure to use `grep -c "^processor" /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: just using `nproc` instead of `grep -c "^processor" /proc/cpuinfo` may be more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You may set the env variable MAKEFLAGS using this command

```
export MAKEFLAGS=-j$(nproc)
```

Comment: @sanmai Works fine for me with 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to have a small script which will run make include all sorts of other features, not just the number of CPUs.

I call my script `mk` and I do a `chmod 755 mk` so I can run it with `./mk` in the root of my project. I also have a few flags to be able to run various things with a simple command line. For example, while working on the code and I get many errors, I like to pipe the output to `less`. I can do that with `./mk -l` without having to retype all the heavy duty Unix stuff...

As you can see, I have the -j4 in a couple of places where it makes sense. For the `-l` option, I don't want it because in this case it would eventually cause multiple errors to be printed at the same time (I tried that before!)

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# Execute make

case "$1" in
"-l")
    make -C ../BUILD/Debug 2>&1 | less -R
    ;;

"-r")
    make -j4 -C ../BUILD/Release
    ;;

"-d")
    rm -rf ../BUILD/Debug/doc/lpp-doc-?.*.tar.gz \
           ../BUILD/Debug/doc/lpp-doc-?.*
    make -C ../BUILD/Debug
    ;;

"-t")
    make -C ../BUILD/Debug
    ../BUILD/Debug/src/lpp tests/suite/syntax-print.logo
    g++ -std=c++14 -I rt l.cpp rt/*.cpp
    ;;

*)
    make -j4 -C ../BUILD/Debug
    ;;

esac

# From the https://github.com/m2osw/lpp project
```

With CMake, it wouldn't work unless, as Tsyvarev mentioned, you create your own script. But I personally don't think it's sensible to call make from your *make script*. Plus it could break a build process which would not expect that *strange script*. Finally, my script, as I mentioned, allows me to vary the options depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use alias in linux to set `cm` equal to `cmake .. && make -j12`. Or write a shell to specify make and clean progress ...

```
alias cm='cmake .. && make -j12'
```

Then use `cm` to make in a single command.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).