# during "${CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL} / 2 + 1" cmake throws "syntax error, unexpected exp_DIVIDE(2)"

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

in `cmake version 3.27.7`

I would like to set number of jobs (for `-j`) to `jobs = jobs//2 + 1` in `CMakeLists.txt` with line

`math(EXPR CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL "${CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL} / 2 + 1" OUTPUT_FORMAT DECIMAL)`

but cmake throws `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (math): math cannot parse the expression: " / 2 + 1": syntax error, unexpected exp_DIVIDE (2).`

my code is wrong or variable `CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL` deserves special treatment? my CPU has 8 threads and I would like to set jobs to 5(or `n//2+1`) for this project

Comment: So, the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL` is **empty** in your case. This can be easily seen from the error message. If you wonder why the variable is empty, why do not directly ask that in the question?

Comment: It is you (as a project's author) who should set the variable. If you want to detect the number of processors in the current system, then you could use `ProcessorCount` functionality, as in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684793/from-cmake-setup-make-to-use-j-option-by-default).